Crontab Expression Help
Need a crontab to run a job on the first Friday after the 18th of every month.  I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Please edit your question and show us the line you have, explaining how it fails.

The logic you need here is something like this:

Run every day for a week after the 18th, i.e. days 19-25.
On each day, check if it's a Friday and only do the actual work if it is.

I.e. something like this:
0 0 19-25 *   [ "$(date +\%u)" = 5 ] && /run/the/actual/script.sh

%u is "Weekday as a decimal number [1,7] (1=Monday)", note that you need to escape the %, since cron uses it as a line separator.
You can't do it directly because of the unintuitive behaviour of the day-of-month and day-of-week fields. In the words of the manpage on my system:

Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields -- day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are  restricted  (i.e.,  aren't
*), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.

There's no way around that within cron itself.

Maybe will be good to replace = with -eq?

@RomeoNinov, hmm, as far as I read the man pages and the POSIX text correctly, %u should give a number without a leading zero, so either should work.
